# How to calculate min height related widget for slide_up_panel in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, position, slide

I'm using slide_up_panel package. I want to give min height for slide_panel which stays under the widget what replaced on the body.

How can I achieve this? I want that my panel stays under the SizedBox(height:24) widget. I also tried getting widget position and use it but it doesn't help.

````
Scaffold(
  appBar: MainAppBar(),
  body: SlidingUpPanel(
    panelBuilder: (ScrollController sc) =>
        LastTransactionDraggableView1(
      _selectedPageIndex.value,
      cardTransactions: state.cardTransactions,
      controller: sc,
    ),
    color: Colour.pinBackground,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.dragRadius),
      topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.dragRadius),
    ),
    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight),
    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - position.dy,
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      color: Colour.primary,
      onRefresh: () async {},
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    MainTabBar(
                        onChange: (index) =>
                            changeTabBar(state, index)),
                    FadeIndexedStack(
                        index: _selectedPageIndex.value,
                        children: [
                          CardPageView(state,
                              hide: state.hideData),
                          AccountPageView(state,
                              hide: state.hideData),
                        ]),
                    SizedBox(height: 24),
                    SizedBox(key: _key)
                  ]),
            );
          },
          valueListenable: _selectedPageIndex),
    ),
  ))

    ```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjbnf.png
````